# problem with a code for string grid ( align center )

Tags: delphi, alignment, center, tstringgrid

[Delphi: How to make cells' texts in TStringGrid center aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540570/delphi-how-to-make-cells-texts-in-tstringgrid-center-aligned/6671671#6671671)

When I use the top code (OnDraw part), it doesn't delete the first text and write the new text on the old text and one sel will duplicate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a call to `TCanvas.FillRect` before writing out the new text:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow];
  StringGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  SetTextAlign(StringGrid1.Canvas.Handle, TA_CENTER);
  StringGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,
    Rect.Left + (Rect.Right - Rect.Left) div 2, Rect.Top + 2, S);
end;
```

Note you'll also have to make sure that the `TStringGrid.DefaultDrawing` is set to `False` in order for this to work.

Comment: thank you but what is the S in your code ? i was changed your code but it dosent worked :

Comment: procedure TF_avalie_salon.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
  var   S: string;

begin
    S := StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow];
    StringGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    SetTextAlign(StringGrid1.Canvas.Handle, TA_CENTER);
    StringGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left + (Rect.Right - Rect.Left) div 2, Rect.Top + 2, S);

end;

Comment: do you want a screen shot from the string grid ?

Comment: The `S` is something I missed when I grabbed the code from your link. Sorry.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to your original question, as it appears I don't understand what the problem is at this point. `FillRect` should solve the problem (unless you're forgetting to set the `StringGrid.DefaultDrawing` to False).

Comment: yoohoo :D it works now . i didnt forget to set DefaultDrawing to false , i didnt knew it , thank you dear . you solve my problem perfectly

Comment: why i cant ask it admin ?

subject :
delphi : move between cells of string grid



buddy :
thank you all for solving my problems and sorry for my many questions

how can i move between cells of a string grid in delphi by tab or arrow keys . as you know , string grid in delphi has only one tab order but i need move between cells by arrow kes or tab for more comfortable and user friendly .

i was tried to use KeyPress event but this event only knows chars and dosent know control keys like tab and ...


tags :
delphi tab-ordering cells tabs arrow

error :
It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: @user: That's a totally separate question, and should be posted as a new one. It has nothing to do with this question. @Downvoter: Padding, because of the way `TextRect`works. I just took it from the previously posted code from the original question's link, so I don't know how 2px was determined.